# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined. Putting styles on classes

Tags: javascript

I have tried to put some background styles, the result was god but it show me that error but I don't know how to put a style with a for statement. Without doing one by one.

Another problem that I have, is that if i do a log of my amarillos. class it says that is `undefined` and that is `false` because in the HTML I defined how amarillos that is yellow in spanish.

All the code works perfectly just one I try to work with my var amarillos I suffer. Thanks

[image]

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Java Script Avanzado</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sesión de Java Script Avanzado</h1>
    <p>Nuestro primer Script en JS Avanzado</p>
    <section id="miSeccion">
      <h1>Listado de texto de los divs</h1>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <div class="miCaja" id="miCaja">
      Hola soy una caja
    </div>
    <div class="rojo">
      Soy el primer div!
    </div>
    <div class="amarillo">
      Soy el segundo div
    </div>
    <div class="amarillo">
      Soy el tercer div
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dom.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

'use strict'

//DOM - Document Object Model

function cambiaColor(color) {
  caja.style.background = color;
}

//Conseguir elementos con un ID concreto
//var caja = document.getElementById('miCaja');

var caja = document.querySelector("#miCaja")

caja.innerHTML = "Texto en la caja desde html";
caja.style.background = "red";
caja.style.padding = "20px";
caja.style.color = "white";
caja.className = "hola";
console.log(caja);

// Conseguir elementos por sus etiqueta
var todosLosDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

var div2 = todosLosDivs[2];
div2.innerHTML = "ya no me gusto lo escrito anterior";
div2.style.background = "yellow";


//todosLosDivs.forEach((valor indice)=>{
var seccion = document.querySelector("#miSeccion")
var hr = document.createElement('hr');

  var valor;
  for(valor in todosLosDivs){

    if (typeof todosLosDivs[valor].textContent == 'string' ) {
      console.log(todosLosDivs[valor]);
      var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
      var texto = document.createTextNode(todosLosDivs[valor].textContent);
      parrafo.append(texto);
      seccion.append(parrafo);
    }
}
seccion.append(hr);

//Conseguir elementos por su clase css
  var amarillos = document.getElementsByClassName("amarillo");
  console.log(amarillos);
  console.log(amarillos.className);
  var color;
  for(color in amarillos){
      amarillos[color].style.background = "yellow";
  }
```

Comment: [edit] post :: remove image and add error as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about that? It really returns a HTMLCollection, which has at each index your element, so you have to specify which index of collection you wish to operate on.

I hope I helped O:-)

Great loop should be that one:

```
    //Conseguir elementos por su clase css
      var amarillos = document.getElementsByClassName("amarillo");

        for (let amarillo of amarillos)
        {
            amarillo.style.background = "yellow";
        }

      console.log(amarillos);
      console.log(amarillos[0]);
      console.log(amarillos[0].style.background);
      console.log(amarillos[0].className);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your 7th line from end like this:

`var amarillos = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("amarillo"));`

As, `document.getElementsByClassName("amarillo")` returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is different from an `Array`